Odd behavior with @ sign
On this answer, Ugam Kamat  left a comment that tagged me with an @sign.
I responded with a comment where I attempted to reciprocate by starting with @UgamKamat, but when the comment was posted, that tag had disappeared.  I'd thought that maybe I'd somehow forgotten to include it, so tried adding another comment (now deleted), but the same thing happened.
Is this a bug, or is it some intentional behavior that I don't understand?  I have not had this happen on other stackexchange sites.
Edited to add: It occurs to me that the @sign was probably superfluous, because I am commenting on Ugam's answer so he'll get notified anyway.  But I am still pretty sure that when I've used the @ sign on other stackexchange sites, it has not disappeared like this.

@Murch ping - verified?.

Yes, if only the post author and you have been commenting on a post thus far, mentions of the author at the beginning of your comment will be removed:

via https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/232061
